# How to grant cv2.VideoWriter permission python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, opencv

I have an django. I create a video with a list of images by using cv2.VideoWriter.
In local with this code :

```
video_name = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'video_test_stream.mp4')
video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, -1, 1, (640, 480))
```

the video file is created and everything works.

But when I push on my ubuntu server, the video file is not created and my app crash.
I think I don't have the good permission on the server but I don't how to add grant and for which user

Comment: Seems more like something to ask on serverfault/superuser/unix than here, since it's really about configuring your server, not any programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned that your code could write video in the local machine,

we assume that all the prerequisites for writing a mp4 video  using opencv has been already installed

(ie ffmpeg package compiled with H.264)

Few suggestions to make sure all prerequisites are available in server

```
    1. ffmpeg package compiled with H.264 is already installed in the server machine.
    2. Installation of open-cv in anaconda will reduce the stress to install ffmpeg package compiled with H.264 
    3. Make sure that the user created in the server machine has got enough privilege to read and write in specific application related directories
        a. Check the read and write permission using the command below
            ls -ld <folder-path>
                   or
            namei -mo <folder-path>
        b. Alter the access writes based on the user privilege required (sudo access needed else we need to engage admin to alter the permission)
            eg : sudo chmod -R 740 <folder-path>** [ Recursive rwx for user ,r for group ]
```